# How to Use Selenium to Click Button/Link on Website in Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm new to Selenium and I'm interested in using its power to open up a bunch of text files for daily reports from the [USDA's website on commodity pricing](https://mymarketnews.ams.usda.gov/viewReport/2837). My eventual goal is to create a time series of historical prices for each commodity.

The data are in text files. I can handle a text file if I have the link and I can then turn into a dataframe for analysis, but **I can't figure out how to perform this operation across all the different text files on the page**.

First, I tried BeautifulSoup with the intent of collecting all the links to the text files in the HTML code and iterating through them. But I realized this wouldn't work because the source code linking to the text files is hidden in Javascript.

Then, I decided to try Selenium. The thought here is I can click the different years and months to get to the text file links. I've come across similar questions around here, but I can't seem to get the **clicking** working.

Firefox pops up to the correct website, but I get errors regardless of how I try to initiate the click. The errors suggest to me that I see something different than what Selenium sees when I inspect element.

Please take a look at the link above if you're interested.

Any thoughts on how to tackle this? Here is an example of me trying to open the "2020s" folder.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\geckodriver-v0.30.0-win64\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get('https://mymarketnews.ams.usda.gov/viewReport/2837')

#link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("2020s")
#link = driver.find_element_by_link_xpath('//*[@id="2020s"]').click()
link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#\32 020s > a:nth-child(1)').click()
```

These are the errors depending on which of the three find_element_by_click lines I run:

```
NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: 2020s

NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //*[@id="2020s"]

InvalidSelectorException: Given css selector expression "# 020s > a:nth-child(1)" is invalid: InvalidSelectorError: Document.querySelector: '# 020s > a:nth-child(1)' is not a valid selector: "# 020s > a:nth-child(1)"
```

I've attached an image of the HTML I see in the inspect element mode before I click the 2020s link/button.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`driver.get()` does not wait for AJAX requests to complete before returning. The element you are trying to click is created via an AJAX request and does not yet exist at the time you are trying to click it.

To get around this, you must first wait for the element to be created, as in the following code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='xxx/geckodriver.exe'))
driver.get('https://mymarketnews.ams.usda.gov/viewReport/2837')
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, '2020s')))
elt = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="2020s"]/a')
elt.click()
```

Two other things to note as you continue to work on this project are

- CSS selectors have a limitation where they cannot be used to find an element with an ID starting with a number.
- You need to click the <a> element directly, not the <li> element surrounding it.

Comment: This is really helpful. It's a big step to go from a controlled environment to the wild west of web scrapping where you need to literally *wait*. Thank you for explaining the code and tips at the end.

Comment: css can do that ftr: `[id="2020s"] a`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this CSS Selector:

```
"#2020s > a"
```

Or Xpath

```
"//*[@id='2020s']/a"
```

Also try to add some wait after `driver.get()`

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html